# onchange for datetimepicker input

Tags: jquery

I am using a for loop in jquery to output data from an ajax call, and one of the HTML lines is:

```
<input type="text" id="deadline_input_' + data[i].data.sequence + '" class="hasDatepicker deadline_input" dateFormat="DD-MM-YYYY" style="display:none;" />
```

and to enable the `datetimepicker`, i am using

```
$('.hasDatepicker').each(function() {
    format = $(this).attr("dateFormat") || "YYYY-MM-DD";

    $(this).datetimepicker({
        format: format,
        minDate: $(this).attr("mindate")
    });
});
```

which works great.

outside of my for loop, i am then checking for a change to the inputs with a class of `deadline_input`

```
$('#results_projects').on('change', '.deadline_input', function() {
    // do something
});
```

which works fine if i remove the above code to enable the `datetimepicker`, but when that is there, it doesn't pickup the change of value on the input

How can i trigger a change when a date is selected in my `datetimepicker`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To catch the datetimepicker onchange event, use `dp.change`

```
$('#results_projects').on('dp.change', '.deadline_input', function() {
    // do something
});
```

Comment: nice! I don't suppose its possible to add an `on close` in there too? I tried `onClose` and `dp.close` but they didn't work

Comment: Great! Try with .on('dp.hide', ...), this should fire when the datetimepicker is hidden.